# Google API mail merge to pdf with email

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am working on a project
The current code and document i have only send an email of what the data in the row is.

I would like that the data in columns B - G be merged to a PDF and then it is sent with the email template to an email address in column H.

I am currently stuck on how to add the code for creating the PDF
Here is the Link to the folder with the google sheets data document [FOLDER LINK](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1PAO4SUwvMw-7LA1faRSroW2APwbYb-PE?usp=sharing)

below is the current code

```
 function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
  var dataRange = dataSheet.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet.getMaxRows() - 1, 4);

  var templateSheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  var emailTemplate = templateSheet.getRange("A1").getValue();

  // Create one JavaScript object per row of data.
  objects = getRowsData(dataSheet, dataRange);

  // For every row object, create a personalized email from a template and send
  // it to the appropriate person.
  for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; ++i) {
    // Get a row object
    var rowData = objects[i];

    // Generate a personalized email.
    // Given a template string, replace markers (for instance ${"First Name"}) with
    // the corresponding value in a row object (for instance rowData.firstName).
    var emailText = fillInTemplateFromObject(emailTemplate, rowData);
    var emailSubject = "Tutorial: Simple Mail Merge";

    MailApp.sendEmail(rowData.emailAddress, emailSubject, emailText);
  } 
}


// Replaces markers in a template string with values define in a JavaScript data object.
// Arguments:
//   - template: string containing markers, for instance ${"Column name"}
//   - data: JavaScript object with values to that will replace markers. For instance
//           data.columnName will replace marker ${"Column name"}
// Returns a string without markers. If no data is found to replace a marker, it is
// simply removed.
function fillInTemplateFromObject(template, data) {
  var email = template;
  // Search for all the variables to be replaced, for instance ${"Column name"}
  var templateVars = template.match(/\$\{\"[^\"]+\"\}/g);

  // Replace variables from the template with the actual values from the data object.
  // If no value is available, replace with the empty string.
  for (var i = 0; i < templateVars.length; ++i) {
    // normalizeHeader ignores ${"} so we can call it directly here.
    var variableData = data[normalizeHeader(templateVars[i])];
    email = email.replace(templateVars[i], variableData || "");
  }

  return email;
}





//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// The code below is reused from the 'Reading Spreadsheet data using JavaScript Objects'
// tutorial.
//
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// getRowsData iterates row by row in the input range and returns an array of objects.
// Each object contains all the data for a given row, indexed by its normalized column name.
// Arguments:
//   - sheet: the sheet object that contains the data to be processed
//   - range: the exact range of cells where the data is stored
//   - columnHeadersRowIndex: specifies the row number where the column names are stored.
//       This argument is optional and it defaults to the row immediately above range; 
// Returns an Array of objects.
function getRowsData(sheet, range, columnHeadersRowIndex) {
  columnHeadersRowIndex = columnHeadersRowIndex || range.getRowIndex() - 1;
  var numColumns = range.getEndColumn() - range.getColumn() + 1;
  var headersRange = sheet.getRange(columnHeadersRowIndex, range.getColumn(), 1, numColumns);
  var headers = headersRange.getValues()[0];
  return getObjects(range.getValues(), normalizeHeaders(headers));
}

// For every row of data in data, generates an object that contains the data. Names of
// object fields are defined in keys.
// Arguments:
//   - data: JavaScript 2d array
//   - keys: Array of Strings that define the property names for the objects to create
function getObjects(data, keys) {
  var objects = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    var object = {};
    var hasData = false;
    for (var j = 0; j < data[i].length; ++j) {
      var cellData = data[i][j];
      if (isCellEmpty(cellData)) {
        continue;
      }
      object[keys[j]] = cellData;
      hasData = true;
    }
    if (hasData) {
      objects.push(object);
    }
  }
  return objects;
}

// Returns an Array of normalized Strings.
// Arguments:
//   - headers: Array of Strings to normalize
function normalizeHeaders(headers) {
  var keys = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < headers.length; ++i) {
    var key = normalizeHeader(headers[i]);
    if (key.length > 0) {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  }
  return keys;
}

// Normalizes a string, by removing all alphanumeric characters and using mixed case
// to separate words. The output will always start with a lower case letter.
// This function is designed to produce JavaScript object property names.
// Arguments:
//   - header: string to normalize
// Examples:
//   "First Name" -> "firstName"
//   "Market Cap (millions) -> "marketCapMillions
//   "1 number at the beginning is ignored" -> "numberAtTheBeginningIsIgnored"
function normalizeHeader(header) {
  var key = "";
  var upperCase = false;
  for (var i = 0; i < header.length; ++i) {
    var letter = header[i];
    if (letter == " " && key.length > 0) {
      upperCase = true;
      continue;
    }
    if (!isAlnum(letter)) {
      continue;
    }
    if (key.length == 0 && isDigit(letter)) {
      continue; // first character must be a letter
    }
    if (upperCase) {
      upperCase = false;
      key += letter.toUpperCase();
    } else {
      key += letter.toLowerCase();
    }
  }
  return key;
}

// Returns true if the cell where cellData was read from is empty.
// Arguments:
//   - cellData: string
function isCellEmpty(cellData) {
  return typeof(cellData) == "string" && cellData == "";
}

// Returns true if the character char is alphabetical, false otherwise.
function isAlnum(char) {
  return char >= 'A' && char <= 'Z' ||
    char >= 'a' && char <= 'z' ||
    isDigit(char);
}

// Returns true if the character char is a digit, false otherwise.
function isDigit(char) {
  return char >= '0' && char <= '9';
}
```

THANK YOU. I HOPE YOU WILL ASSIST ME

Answer (score 0):

This script will allow you to reference a sheet and send it as a PDF to any specified email address.

```js
// Generate a PDF file from a Google spreadsheet and send it to a specified email address
function emailSpreadsheetAsPDF() {
  const sheetToPrint = "SPREADSHEET NAME"; // name of the sheet to print
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // the sheets to use
  const email = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('SHEET NAME').getRange('E3').getValue().toString(); // grab the email address from the specified cell 
  const subject = `SUBJECT - ${ss.getName()}`; // the subject of the email
  const body = "BODY"; // body of the email
  const shID = ss.getSheetByName(sheetToPrint).getSheetId(); // the ID of the sheet
  const url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SS_ID/export?'.replace('SS_ID', ss.getId()); // url of the spreadsheet
  const exportOptions =
    'exportFormat=pdf&format=pdf' + // export as pdf / csv / xls / xlsx
    '&size=A4'+ // size of the PDF (legal / A4 / letter)
    '&portrait=true'+ // orientation of the PDF (false for landscape)
    '&fitw=true'+ // fit to page width (false for actual size)
    '&sheetnames=false&printtitle=false'+ // hide optional headers and footers
    '&pagenumbers=false&gridlines=false'+ // hide page numbers and gridlines
    '&fzr=false'+ // do not repeat row headers (frozen rows) on each page
    '&gid='+shID; // the sheet's Id
  var params = {method:"GET",headers:{"authorization":"Bearer "+ ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}};
  
  // generate the PDF file
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url+exportOptions, params).getBlob();
  
  // send the email to the specified address with the specified body text and attached PDF file
    GmailApp.sendEmail(email, subject, body, {
      htmlBody: body,
      attachments: [{
            fileName: `FILE NAME - ${ss.getName()}` + ".pdf",
            content: response.getBytes(),
            mimeType: "application/pdf"
        }]
    });
}
```

It is very easy to implement. All you have to do is change the `SPREADSHEET NAME`, `SHEET NAME`, `SUBJECT`, `BODY`, and `FILE NAME`. Changing around the `ExportOptions` could also potentially help you.

If you have any questions, do not hesitate to contact me.

Comment: What I would like is that each row is created into a PDF which when I run a script will send an email with the PDF attachment as well as save a copy of the PDF on Drive.